# Is it possible to call object's method via `do` keyword?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I prefer the standard coffeescript syntax, so I don't use brackets where possible.

---

So, I have some object. For example,

```
let obj = {
    с = 0;
    a(x) {
        this.c+=x;
        return this;
    },
    b() {
        this.c++;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Ok, everything's clear here. But, what if I call `a`?

```
obj
.a 5
.a 15
# etc
```

Here's clear too.

---

But, how to call `b` afer calling `a`, if i don't want to use the brackets`()`?

```
obj
.a 5
.a 15
.do b
```

- compiles to

```
obj.a(5).a(15).do(b);
```

But i expect

```
obj.a(5).a(15).b();
```

---

**So, how to call `b` without passing any parameters after calling `a` method,


without using the brackets`()`?**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Writing it without brackets will treat it as a property or variable. Read [this article](https://gist.github.com/myobie/3792225) as to why you cannot write it without them. One way to write it without brackets is to provide it with a parameter, such as null, but this is uglier that writing ().